# Remove duplicate labels from matplotlib subplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making 2 plots on a page using `matplotlib.pyplot` each with twin axes.  An example of the code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 30

x = np.arange(n)
a = np.random.rand(n)
b = np.random.rand(n)
c = np.random.rand(n)
d = np.random.rand(n)

fig = plt.figure()

# ... upper plot

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.step(x, a, '-', color='k', label="series 1")
ax2.step(x, b, 'o', color='r', label="series 2")

fig.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.00, 1.00), bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes)

# ... lower plot

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

ax3.step(x, c, '-', color='b', label="series 3")
ax4.step(x, d, 'o', color='g', label="series 4")

fig.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.00, 1.00), bbox_transform=ax3.transAxes)
```

The issue is that the lower plot has the labels from both the upper and lower plot eg.
[image]

How do I remove the upper plot labels from the lower plot? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 30

x = np.arange(n)
a = np.random.rand(n)
b = np.random.rand(n)
c = np.random.rand(n)
d = np.random.rand(n)

fig = plt.figure()

# ... upper plot

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.step(x, a, '-', color='k', label="series 1")
ax2.step(x, b, 'o', color='r', label="series 2")

ax1.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.8), bbox_transform=ax2.transAxes)

# ... lower plot

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()

ax3.step(x, c, '-', color='b', label="series 3")
ax4.step(x, d, 'o', color='g', label="series 4")

ax3.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.00, 1.00), bbox_transform=ax3.transAxes)
ax4.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.00, 0.8), bbox_transform=ax4.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image]
I changed my code again and hope this will help you. Take a look at this link and if it will solve your question, please make it as answered and vote up for bounty.

Comment: Hi I changed my code as you suggested but now I get 2 separate plots.  I need to have both plots on the same page

Comment: Hi thanks for the update.  It works but what I would like ideally is to have a single legend box on each plot rather than separate legend for each series.  The real life example has several series plotted on each subplot

Comment: Aha, ok I will check and see if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ax*.legend()` on each axis and the labels will show up in the correct plot. If you don't pass the `loc` argument to `legend()`, it will put it at a place it thinks best. If you want a specific position, you could specify it e.g. `ax1.legend(loc="upper left")`.

Comment: Hi - I tried this but I only get the legend for the chosen axis eg `ax2.legend()` only shows the labels for ax2

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. But this should allow you to show labels for any number of axes on the same plot. Try doing `ax1.legend()` and `ax2.legend` separately and then together at the same time.